# Evaluating a macro when form is read from a string

Tags: macros, common-lisp, eval

I have a macro `with-voice`:

```
(defmacro with-voice (tag body)
  `(format nil "<span class=\"~a\">~%~a~%</span>" ',tag ,body))
```

which emits some text surrounded by a  tag with some class. I know there are great libraries like CL-WHO - but I just need something tiny...

```
CL-USER> (with-voice narrator "foo")
"<span class=\"NARRATOR\">
foo
</span>"
```

which is is the desired outcome

I would like to be able to do this from a string

```
(let ((s (read-from-string "(with-voice narrator \"foo\")")))
  (print (eval s)))
```

This works:

```
CL-USER> (let ((s (read-from-string "(with-voice narrator \"foo\")")))
  (print (eval s)))

"<span class=\"NARRATOR\">
foo
</span>" 
"<span class=\"NARRATOR\">
foo
</span>
```

but it has the dreaded `eval`. I've tried to get this working using macros and lambdas, but I can't get it working.

I'd be grateful for some help

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could funcall the symbol you expect in a certain position of the read form:

```
(destructuring-bind (operator class text)
    (read-from-string "(with-voice narrator \"foo\")")
  (funcall operator class text))
```

Or even just expect those forms to be funcallable:

```
(apply #'funcall (read-from-string "(with-voice narrator \"foo\")"))
```

If you have more different shapes of data, you might want to match those, e. g. using `optima`, or using dispatch by `eql` specializer.  This can also help with validation if the read input might contain harmful intent.

Comment: Excellent -thank you and I will use your suggestion. I have re-written "with-voice" as a function and your snippet works exactly as I require.

For my education, is the situation I describe one where eval might be "ok" to use?

```

Comment: I think it is generally better to have an intermediate parsing/validation step, since the input to `eval` tends to originate from outside the system.  I have not yet encountered a case where `eval` would have made things clearer than not using it (except maybe in the inner workings of a compiler).

Comment: I see. I guess that's one of the advantages of using sexprs - often, parsing is not too hard. Thanks again.